# Looking for help with AICC compliant LMS in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am in the process of creating an [AICC](http://www.aicc.org) (Aviation Industry CBT Committee) compliant LMS using Classic ASP. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: You might want to add links on those acronyms. I just had to Google both of them. Although, I suppose your target audience (..not me) will already know what they mean :)

Comment: No fair - most of the links I've tried to fish info from are rubbish :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd quite like to know how to develop courseware that runs on an AICC compliant LMS! I come from a SCORM background and need to replace all of my SCORM API calls with AICC ones - apparently this might involve XMLHTTPRequest.

In partial answer to your question though, check out [moodle.org](http://moodle.org) as they have an AICC module, and the LMS itself is OpenSource so you can get stuck in to the icky details. You'll have to live with the fact that its written in PHP though, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: I need to launch an AICC course and receive communications back to my LMS which currently supports SCORM specifications and supports only AICC launch request of my own courses from other LMSs. How can I add the capability to launch & manage third party AICC courses? My code is written in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Server-side should be the same as a SCORM implementation (of which there is ample information). Client-side, the calls and data objects seem very similar to the SCORM object (probably 1.2).

This page seems to have very helpful information: http://www.cen-ltso.net/main.aspx?put=241&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

And this link looks to define the data object structure: http://www.immagic.com/eLibrary/TECH/AICC_US/A040816G.pdf

At least, those are the links that I will be primarily working with. Until it all dead-ends into sadness of course.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you want to do it in classic asp?   AICC HACP and API are very simple protocols depending on the level of compliance to the standard you need/want.  To answer directly, yes Im an expert specifically in AICC and asp classice,.net and such.

Comment: Come on. The world's moved on in 3 years.

Comment: I need to launch an AICC course and receive communications back to my LMS which currently supports SCORM specifications and supports only AICC launch request of my own courses from other LMSs. How can I add the capability to launch & manage third party AICC courses? My code is written in asp.net